# How to dynamically set image in iOS

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, tableview

I have following code:

```
     NSMutableArray *arrayImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"camera.jpg",@"washMachine.jpg",@"mixer.jpg",@"tv.jpg",@"mobile.jpg",@"fridge.jpg",@"frock.jpg",@"shirt.jpg",nil];  

  for(int i=0; i<_devicePriceArray.count;i++){
         [_deviceArray addObject:arrayImages];
     }
```

And in my

```
   cellForRowAtIndexPath :- I am trying to set the images 

 [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:201] setImage:[_deviceArray[indexPath.row]];
```

How do I set the images here? It's saying "Expected identifier".

Answer (score 0):

Observe the line

`[(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:201] setImage:[arrayImages[indexPath.row]];`.

Here you just use the image name. Where as you have to pass `UIImage` object here. Replace it with below line

```
[(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:201] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:arrayImages[indexPath.row]]];
```

Comment: This threw me following error:         *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ce5620'

Comment: Here now you have Array as an object of array. So please make it clear. You have an array which contains array of multiple images right?

Comment: sorry about it. For some reason, i want it to be as in my edit. you are right- an array which contains array of multiple images

Comment: So you can not set mulitple images for one `UIImageView`. For that you have to create more than one `UIImageView`, and than set these images. I suggest you to create custom cell for that would be much easier to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:arrayImages[indexPath.row]];
```